# Taylor formula for two variables mapping

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let $f\in \mathcal{C}^2(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R}^d)$, I know that in the case of one dimension :

$$f(x,b)-f(a,b)=\int_0^1\partial_x f(a+\alpha(x-a),b)\times(x-a)d\alpha.$$

I wonder if there's any formula for $2$ variables :

$$f(x,y)-f(a,b)=\int_0^1\int_0^1\partial_x f(a+\alpha(x-a),b)\times(x-a)+\partial_y f(a,b+\beta(y-b))\times(y-b) d\beta d\alpha.$$
Is this formula true ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second equation in your post is not true. The correct one is
\begin{align}
  & f(x,y)-f(a,b)\\
= & \int_0^1 [\partial_x f(a+\alpha(x-a),b+\alpha(y-b))\times(x-a)
+ \partial_y f(a+\alpha(x-a),b+\alpha(y-b))\times(y-b) ]  d\alpha.
\end{align}

---

**Proof**
\begin{align}
& \int_0^1 [\partial_x f(a+\alpha(x-a),b+\alpha(y-b))\times(x-a)
+ \partial_y f(a+\alpha(x-a),b+\alpha(y-b))\times(y-b) ] d\alpha\\
& = \int_0^1 \frac{\partial f}{\partial \alpha}(a+\alpha(x-a),b+\alpha(y-b)) d\alpha\\
& = f((a+\alpha(x-a),b+\alpha(y-b))|_0^1\\
& = f(x,y)-f(a,b).
\end{align}